# Where is the system-wide dark mode setting in Linux?

Tags: kde, gtk, qt, theme, dark-mode

I'm using the Raspberry Pi version of Debian, which has both GTK and KDE programs, as well as bygone era programs like xpdf that still work just fine.
If I wanted to tell apps that I prefer Dark Mode, where would I add that setting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike e.g. MacOS, there is not just one setting.

1. Switching to Xfce will make life easier than struggling with whatever Raspberry pi OS is imposing (Lxsession or some such).
2. Go to: Settings -> Appearance -> choose Adwaita Dark theme
3. Go to: Settings -> QT5 settings -> GTK2 theme
4. Firefox: Choose the dark theme.
5. Ungoogled Chromium should also have a dark theme.

Answer (score 0):

There's no such setting in Linux yet. The only way to "enable" dark mode currently is to change your toolkit (GTK/Qt) theme and that depends on your distro and desktop environment. Some applications like e.g. Firefox/Thunderbird have internal settings to enable dark mode. Some applications using these two major toolkits don't respect toolkit theming settings, e.g. Google Chrome or VirtualBox (the official version).

Some toolkits don't support theming at all.

Answer (score 0):

There used to be a `gtk-application-prefer-dark-theme=1` flag for GTK3 applications (placed in *~/.config/gtk-3.0/settings.ini* file), but for some reason it stopped working some years ago (feature removed, maybe?): https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/GTK#Dark_theme_variant